# How to calculate a simple chord progression (C major)

Tags: chord-theory

Good day,

I don't remember and cannot find any information about the "formula" I got from my music teacher very long time ago which establish a simple chord progression, let's say in C

C major, D minor, E minor, F major, G major, A minor, B dim

So, why the 2nd, 3rd and 6th chords are minor?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated

Thank you

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Due to each triad being made up from 'stacked thirds' using diatonic notes.

Let's take each in turn: C E G =Cmaj. D F A =Dm. E G B= Em. F A C = Fmaj. G B D =Gmaj. A C E = Am. B D F=Bo.

Dm Em and Am are all minors because their thirds (F G and C respectively) are all minor thirds Were they major chords, those notes would be F♯, G♯ and C♯ respectively. None of which is in the notes diatonic to C major.